# Java linked list that supports fast removal of any nodes?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

The java.util.LinkedList does not allow you to quickly remove a given object in the list. The remove(object) method performs a linear search to find the object in the list so it can remove it. Since this is a double linked-list, it would be nice to remove by just updating the pointers (node.prev and node.next).

What is the Java standard solution for this problem?

NOTE1: I don't want to remove while iterating. I know that is fast, but I am not iterating through my elements in the first place.

NOTE2: To make it simple: Given an object O that I know it is in a double linked-list, I want to quickly remove O from that list (by updating the pointers) without having to linear search for it in the list, as java.util.LinkedList does.

Comment: If you remove it using the iterator it doesn't perform the search again.

Comment: Either I don't understand your question, or you don't understand how double linked-lists work.  Are you sure you should be using linked lists?  Perhaps another category of storage is more appropriate?  Any clarification you can add to help me understand what you're *really* getting at?

Comment: Added a note. I do NOT want to remove while iterating.

Comment: You may want to use a `Set`... of course, this depends on your use case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should take a look at the [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) class. Basically it's a HashSet that maintains a doubly-linked list among its entries. It supports retrieval (and thus also deletion) of an element in O(1) (hopefully). Check the link for the specification on the how it handles the elements order in case of reinserting an entry and other details.

**EDIT:**

If you need to store duplicates you can take a look at the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [LinkedHashMultiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultiset.html) (never used so far).  The Guava user guide on Multiset is [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset).

Comment: That looks like the best option so far. Or course the only drawback is that it does NOT support duplicates in the list.

Comment: You can implement equals (or not implement it) so there are no duplicates.

Comment: chrisapotek you're right. LinkedHashSet extends HashSet and thus no duplicates are allowed (only 1 null value as well). @PeterLawrey be careful not implementing equals or hashcode when dealing with HashStuff... pavelrappo :|??

Comment: Many classes don't implement equals/hashCode because even if the contents are the same, they are not considered the same object.

Comment: @PeterLawrey right, that is true in certain cases. Still, not implementing equals or hashCode needs particular attentions because it might make using a HashCollections useless (in terms of performances) if one doesn't keep a reference to the original Object somewhere else. It depends on chrisapotek needs and the specific domain. Another solution would be taking a look at Guava's LinkedHashMultiset.

Comment: You could add a count field to the object if the duplicates are basically identical or use a `Map<Type, Integer>` instead.

Comment: `LinkedHashMultiset` is almost always simpler than `Map<Type, Integer>`.

Answer (score 2):

I bet you that the implementation of `LinkedList#remove()` does remove it by updating the pointers to the previous and next items - the problem is, it has to loop over all objects until it finds the proper one to remove.

If you want a collection that removes faster, without iterating over all the objects, use a `Set` or a `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a composite object. Create a class that contains your list, while also maintaining an index into that list.

So when wanting to do a fast remove, you do a constant time index lookup, to get a reference to the list element you wish to remove, followed by a constant time removal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm primarily a C programmer learning Java. I found this thread because I was also wondering why there was no linked list implementation where you could just remove the object directly without searching for it. Searching linearly is incredibly inefficient. A list backed with a hash table is better, but you don't really know how the hash table is going to perform.

The reason you can do this easily in C is because normally the list element object itself contains the next and previous pointers, so given the object, it's a simple matter of manipulating a couple of pointers to remove the element from the list, so it's an O(1) operation. In Java, you have the object, but you don't have direct access to the pointers because they are maintained separately within the list. Thus, you have to search for the object either linearly or with a hash table.

It seems like one could solve this problem by creating a linked list implementation where every object type added to the list would have to implement a LinkedListElement interface which would support getting and setting the next and previous pointers. You would have to add next and previous pointers to your class and implement the functions to get and set them. The links list class would then be able to easily remove an object because the object itself contains the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to work using the [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) where possible.  It's `remove` will be constant time.

The Java standard library does not have a separate linked list node structure, so I think `ListIterator` is the best option.

Comment: You still need to search for the item in the list, which is O(n) time. Once that is found, then yes, removing it will be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a map would be appropriate. It gives *expected* O(1) removal time. But then again you didn't specify what *fast* means.

A list backed by a BST could also work. It would give log(n) removal time.

For the solutions listed here I assumed something faster that iterating through the list, so anything faster than O(n);